# Android: How to measure how long takes to load HTML?

Tags: android, logging

I'm loading some `HTML` to my `WebView`. I found some ways to improve it but I don't see them working. I thought I need to focus on how much time is spent on the actual `HTML` loading. Is there any possibility to check it and print in the console (log)?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24897995/6244429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override your webView like this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        long startTime;
        long elapsedTime;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            Log.v("webview", "total elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
});
```

The result is in milliseconds.

Comment: Is that called automatically?

Comment: Hmm, I think it can be called automatically, since you don't have to count it manually with a stopwatch, right?

Comment: Yup, but I put the code into my app but there is nothing in android monitor nor in the run console

Comment: Hmm, weird. Maybe it never finished. Try to put another log Log.v("webview", "starting time: " + startTime); on the onPageStarted method.

Comment: It is not printed too

Comment: But do the page loaded? You call the above code directly after you assign your webView variable right? Maybe you can try to debug to make sure the method is called.

Comment: i don't call it I just add it to the webview, page is loaded

Comment: I mean you put the above code before you the mWebView.loadUrl(url); line right?

Comment: Hmm, okay. Sorry, seems like I can't help much.

Comment: Well, I forgot that I had another `WebViewClient` which was overriding this one. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
long endTime;
webview.loadData(data);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  endTime = System.nanoTime();
}
});


long MethodeDuration = (endTime - startTime);
```